# How to use Redis for checking availablity of a person

Tags: algorithm, redis

Lets consider a meeting request where i can find if a person is available in a particular time slot.

Example:  I need to check if person is available for meeting from 3 to 3:30. So if a person is busy from 2:30 to 3:01 means person is unavailable.

Question: how can i use the redis cache here.
Do i need to store cache of every minute of a user and can then application decides or any other way ?

Comment: Hi, perhaps store the last known state when it changes?

Comment: What do you mean by last state... A calender can be booked like from 8-9, 11,12 which means u r free from 9 to 11

Comment: Nah just store their schedule for that day as an interval tree then do a query on if there is any overlap in the provided interval with the ones in the database. If any chance a meeting goes past midnight, you'll need to make sure to check the previous day to see if that occurs (since they would be unavailable from midnight until it ends). Likely more of an issue if you have to deal with timezones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if Redis is the data store that I'd choose for this task.

Still, if you're willing to work in a 1 minute resolution then you could store the minutes in which a person is occupied inside a [Sorted Set](https://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) of minutes, and then check if a time range overlaps that person's scheduled appointments with the `ZINTER` command.

Comment: Which cache/data-store you will choose ?

Comment: Also you mean1440 values need to be stored for every user?

Comment: @nikhilroadi It depends on many other factors, but the natural candidate would be PostgreSQL because of it's ability to use range data types and GIST indexes in order to speed up such queries.

Comment: @nikhilroadi yes I meant that you would store 1440 slots per day. To be more exact, you would only store those slots that are occupied. That's not 1440 keys, but up to 1440 items inside a single ordered set.

Comment: 1 minute is worst case solution, there must be a better solution.